# Conditional Formatting Excel Rows Based On Relationship To TODAY()

Tags: excel, formatting, format

I am trying to use 3 rules to format the row 3 separate colours based on the information in various cells.

[Example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOedz.png)

I am trying to get the whole row to operate a traffic light system:
Amber if there is a date in Date Rcvd
Red if either Due Date is before Today
Green if Invoice Date is not blank.

the amber and green rules appear to work using the following:

=NOT(ISBLANK(A2)) to turn row amber, =IF(D2,TRUE) to turn row green but =OR($B2 < TODAY(),$C2 < TODAY()) does not turn row red if due dates are missed, I have tried various And/IFs etc but I cannot get this to work.

Your help is greatly appreciated as I'd love to get this working to impress in new job

Comment: Since you are not testing the same cell in each of your rules, depending on the order only one will fire.  If you want the last to fire always make sure it has precedent over the others.

Answer (score 1):

> the amber and green rules appear to work

so just considering

> Red if either Due Date is before Today

Please select ColumnsA:D and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(ROW()<>1,$B1<>"",MAX($B1,$C1)<TODAY())
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red colour Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

As mentioned by @Scott Craner, you may have to decide on the priorities for the three colours and order accordingly, perhaps applying Stop if True to suit.